# How to remove dynamically generated classname in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

Here is a dynamic generated class by mat checkbox ,  in a function call, i need to remove a class.

Here is a tag matinput chechbox generated while check and uncheck

```
<mat-pseudo-checkbox class="mat-option-pseudo-checkbox mat-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked" ng-reflect-state="checked" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></mat-pseudo-checkbox>
```

In this class , need to remove last portion of the class.This checkbox control is thirdparty controls.

`mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked`

```
class="mat-option-pseudo-checkbox mat-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked".
```

The screen looks like this

[image]

In this output what is happening means two values gets cleared and getting null but select box is selected for pune

Comment: Why would you do that  ? What is the end goal ?

Comment: @trichetriche which is a filterselect control , in the filter select contains lots of values with checkbox, if i select the checkbox, at that i am reset the controls the value gets cleared, but the checkbox is getting selected in the control , in this scenario i need to remove the class `mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked`.which will solve the problem.

Comment: If you reset the form and the box still is checked, then your issue is in your code, not in Material. Consider reproducing your issue in a [mcve] on https://stackbltz.io.

Comment: which is custom form control by third party , the code has not been exposed, if i disable the form , which is not disable but the form status is disable.,anyway thanks for the comment.

Comment: Make a [mcve] reproducing the issue before blaming anything.

Comment: sorry , i am not blame anyone  , i know its there control issue , for time being i need an alternative workaround for that thats what i have asked this question, and also know that difficult to understand others by dont provide  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, therefore i have asked  to remove a class name if possible i will create a demo for better understanding.

Comment: Ok I already have asked two times, I give up. Your code/workflow has an issue, not Material. You don't want to provide an MCVE ? Fine, here is my answer : You can't do what you ask. This is a runtime addition, you can't select it from your Angular component. You'll have to go out of your way to be able to do that. Good luck with your issue.